# Multiple inclusion of GetPot

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I'm facing a problem with GetPot (http://getpot.sourceforge.net/), namely the fact that when I include it more than once I get a `multiple definition` error by the linker.

Here's a MWE:

file `main.cpp`:

```
#include "GetPot"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "GetPot"

void foo()
{
    GetPot configurationFileParser("foobar");
    double bar = configurationFileParser("bar", 0.0);
}
```

(all GetPot files, that is `GetPot`, `GetPot.hpp` and `GetPot.cpp`, are in the same directory as `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp`).

Compiling with `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp`, I get:

```
/tmp/ccD22ma0.o: In function `GetPot::__constraint_check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, bool) const':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `GetPot::__constraint_check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, bool) const'
/tmp/ccxM8JHn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccD22ma0.o: In function `GetPot::__constraint_check_OR(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x5ca): multiple definition of `GetPot::__constraint_check_OR(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const'
/tmp/ccxM8JHn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5ca): first defined here
/tmp/ccD22ma0.o: In function `GetPot::__constraint_check_AND(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x752): multiple definition of `GetPot::__constraint_check_AND(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const'
/tmp/ccxM8JHn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x752): first defined here
/tmp/ccD22ma0.o: In function `GetPot::__constrain_check_EQUAL_STRING(char const*, char const**) const':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x692): multiple definition of `GetPot::__constrain_check_EQUAL_STRING(char const*, char const**) const'
/tmp/ccxM8JHn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x692): first defined here
/tmp/ccD22ma0.o: In function `GetPot::__constraint_check_PRIMARY(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x81e): multiple definition of `GetPot::__constraint_check_PRIMARY(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const**) const'
/tmp/ccxM8JHn.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81e): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
(ins)mattia@endor:getpot-c++$
```

On the other hand, compiling `GetPot.cpp` into an object file `GetPot.o` and then simply including `GetPot.hpp` in my source files will not work either, since `GetPot::operator()` is only declared in `GetPot.cpp`, hence the error:

```
/tmp/ccSIAz1V.o: In function `foo()':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `double GetPot::operator()<double>(StringOrCharP, double) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
(ins)mattia@endor:getpot-c++$
```

In any case, this whole problem baffles me, since both `GetPot.hpp` and `GetPot.cpp` have include guards, so multiple definitions should not happen in the first place.

What am I doing wrong? Is there really no way to include GetPot more than once in a collection of files (in particular, for example, when writing a library)?

Thank you very much

Mattia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetPot` should only be included in one file. Otherwise, you might consider going through the member functions and make *inline* what is not *inline*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

I see your point, though this seems like a strange behaviour, doesn't it? This effectively forces the user to only be able to parse configuration files in a single source file, instead of having the possibility to use the parsing capabilities across, say, a library.

Comment: Yeah, this behavior is strange. Your comment should translate into a bug or feature request.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that! Thank you very much indeed!